# How to call a page inside a div with flash?

Tags: jquery, flash, actionscript-2

I need to call a page inside a div, but with flash!

I have this script on my page:

```
$('#bt_aoptica').click(function () {
        $('#my_site_content').load("aoptica.html");
        $("#menu ul li a").not(this).removeClass("currentMenu");
        $(this).toggleClass("currentMenu");         
});
```

and this works perfectly with my menu!

How i call this with actionscript 2??

Ty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this is what you are looking for but if not :) sorry

http://codingrecipes.com/calling-a-javascript-function-from-actionscript-3-flash

**AS2**

```
getURL('javascript:fromFlash();')
```

**JS**

```
function fromFlash(){
   // put ur javascript/jquery instructions here
}
```

Comment: hum.. i need this in actionscript 2, but i dont understand how to call a jquery function..

Comment: check the answer is updated now :) if u get stuck http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=156229 is a good example of ur problem

Comment: hum.. yeah ty works fine... another question:

how u can see i'm loading an html page inside a div in another page ok?.. my flash with this javascrip is on the page i was loading. How to comunicate with page thats contain the div... ? u understand me?

Comment: ok..  i have a index.html . Inside i have a div with id=my_site_content. when i click on the contact button on menu, i call the jquery i have posted in my question, thats load another page inside this div. This another page, have the flash, and this flash have the javascrit you have posted in your answer. If i put your script in index.html dont work, and if i put on another page thats contain flash, dont work too...

Comment: only works if i have the flash and the div on same page. i Think i need to call with parent function right?.. 

the jquery code i want execute is: 
$('#my_site_content').load("aoptica.html");